# React-Select. Автоматическая подгрузка данных

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, html-select, autoload

Имеется задача: при вводе каких-либо букв в текстовом поле `Search` подгружать с сервера данные. Однако сервер отдаёт данные порционно, то есть не все данные, соответствтвующие тому, что мы ввели, а частями по 20 элементов. И собственно было бы хорошо подгружать автоматически данные при скролле до последнего элемента в списке. Имеется ли какая-то возможность сделать такое при помощи `React-Select`? (https://react-select.com/home)